Accessing RabbitMQ using WebStomp (stompjs) works on localhost only
I´m using RabbitMQ broker with multiple clients via AMQP (.NET WebAPI, MAUI...) working with no issues connecting to broker on remote server (Azure VM). But for React web client we have to use WebStomp for same purpose (just consuming messages from queue). Am using own user accounts, not guest/guest for that.
Web client is only one not able to connect to RabbitMQ on remote server (WebSocket connection to 'ws://DOMAIN:15674/ws' failed), when using localhost it works fine directly on VM. Azure and windows firewall is set to allow 15674 same as for AMQP 5672 (which is working fine locally and remotely).
When trying to connect with webstomp from remote I can even see connection attempts on server netstat.
  TCP    10.x.x.13:15674        136.x.x.81:13951   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    10.x.x.13:15674        136.x.x.81:26239   TIME_WAIT
  TCP    10.x.x.13:15674        136.x.x.81:30143   TIME_WAIT
Any idea what I´m missing?
Expectation is just to be able to read messages from RabbitMQ queues using webstomp client same as AMQP ones are working.
